# Selection list with select values on pressing keys 1,2,3,4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an option list with some japanese text in it like this:

```
<select name="era" class="form-control form-smallItem">
   <option value="">--</option>
   <option value="4">平成</option>
   <option value="3">昭和</option>
   <option value="2">大正</option>
   <option value="1">明治</option>
</select>
```

I want to select the options by key press of 1, 2, 3, and 4 in HTML. If I press 1 it should display "明治" if 2 - "大正", ... etc.

Do I need to write a special Javascript on keypress? OR Does HTML 5 have any other attribute to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write some javascript for this behaviour.

By default, browsers (HTML5 or otherwise) generally select `<select>` options based on key-presses matching the text, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below, it should support single character values

```
$('select[name="era"]').keypress(function (e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $(this).find('option[value="' + char + '"]').prop('selected', true);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2qJ3w/)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/K6by2/

add Keyup function to any element you want to apply this event to..

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    var sel = $('select[name=era]');
    if (key == 49) {
        sel.val(1);
    } else if (key == 50) {
        sel.val(2)
    } else if (key == 51) {
        sel.val(3)
    } else if (key == 52) {
        sel.val(4)
    }
});
```